# Getting error while fetching orders from salesforce sfcc

Tags: javascript, node.js, salesforce

While executing the below code I am getting the token such format like Bearer {token}

Now While gitting the getOrderList() I am getting a 400 Bad Request error.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong? I am using this https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FOCAPI%2F15.2%2Fshop%2FResources%2FOrders.html as a reference to fetch all orders from the salesforce while is created recently.

Can anyone help me with this thing?

```
'use strict';
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const ocapi_path = require('./ocapi_path');

const envDomain = 'Domainhere';
const envClientId = 'clientidHere';
const getToken = async (domain = envDomain, clientId = envClientId) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${domain}/s/site-id/dw/shop/v19_1/customers/auth?client_id=${clientId}`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ type: 'guest' }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      },
    },
  );
  if (!response.ok) {
    const json = await response.json();
    throw new Error(`OCAPI error response: ${JSON.stringify(json)}`);
  }

  return response.headers.get('Authorization');
};

const getOrderList = async (token) => {
  const domain = envDomain;
  const response = await fetch(
    `${domain}/s/site-id/dw/shop/v19_1/orders?status=completed`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': token,
        Authorization: token,
      },
    },
  );
  if (response.ok) {
    return await response.json();
  }

  return null;
};


const getTheResult = async () => {
    const token =  await getToken();
    const result =  await getOrderList(token);
    console.log(result);
}

getTheResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to exchange the access token for session credentials and then use those to call the Orders API.

1. Retrieve token for `guest` (you've done this)
2. [Exchange token for session creds](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/current/usage/SessionBridge.html?resultof=%22%2F%64%77%2F%73%68%6F%70%2F%76%32%30%5F%32%2F%63%75%73%74%6F%6D%65%72%73%2F%61%75%74%68%22%20):

> To obtain a session for a guest or registered customer
>   you have to pass a valid JWT to /sessions resource. The JWT has to be
>   passed as Authorization:Bearer request header. In case of success you
>   get the session cookies back.

```
REQUEST:
POST /dw/shop/v20_2/sessions HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
x-dw-client-id: ...
Authorization: Bearer <token>

RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 204 NO CONTENT
Set-Cookie : dwsecuretoken_a85a5236a2e852d714eb6f1585efb61c=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT;
Set-Cookie : dwsid=eXv5R3FZGI4BBfbK1Opk5s1mJ-41Aw7ZuaMKxeye5xa16fJMX--AnNkXsvmakbi1UZSzP1zoPmUILgoom1_jKg==;
Set-Cookie : dwanonymous_a85a5236a2e852d714eb6f1585efb61c=bdjalnzmfrkJ0FtYliwud5db67; Max-Age=15552000;
Cache-Control: max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
```

3. Call Order API with session creds from previous step:

```
REQUEST:
GET /dw/shop/v15_2/orders?status=completed HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Cookie: dwsecuretoken_a85a5236a2e852d714eb6f1585efb61c="";dwsid=eXv5R3FZGI4BBfbK1Opk5s1mJ-41Aw7ZuaMKxeye5xa16fJMX--AnNkXsvmakbi1UZSzP1zoPmUILgoom1_jKg==; dwanonymous_a85a5236a2e852d714eb6f1585efb61c=bdjalnzmfrkJ0FtYliwud5db67;
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
   "_v" : "15.2",
   "count" : ...,
   "data" : [...],
   ...
}
```

Comment: getting this error  "type": "InvalidAccessTokenException",
        "message": "The request is unauthorized, the access token is invalid."